# Microsoft _s functions, are they part of the C++ standard now?

Tags: c++, standards

I just recently changed my IDE to MS Visual Studio 2005 coming from MSVC++ 6, and I've gotten a lot of deprecation warnings.  Rather than ignore the warning, I started to change them to the _s equivalents.  However, I then found out that these were microsoft-only implementations.

I read somewhere that they were pushing for these to become part of the standard. Is it?

Is it a good idea to use these _s functions? Or should I use something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Because Microsoft have covered themselves in glory with the OOXML standards debacle, I'm sure ISO is falling over themselves in order to incorporate all their stuff into the C++ standard :-)

Comment: I can't tell if this is sarcasm or not. :(

Comment: More humor than sarcasm. Apologies. My wife would agree with you that my sense of humor is sometimes strange.

Comment: @paxdiablo: maybe a bit late, but you do realize that Herb Sutter works at MS?^^

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `*_s()` functions are not part of the C standard, but there is a pending 'Technical Report' proposing that they be added (I'm not sure if the routines in the TR are exactly the same as Microsoft's or if they're just similar).

TR 24731-1: Extensions to the C Library Part I: Bounds-checking interfaces:

- http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1225.pdf

If you want to continue to use the old functions you can keep the deprecation warnings quiet by defining the macro `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` (was `_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` which might still be supported).

Comment: Just to support, _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE works on some like strncpy, etc, while for others like fopen() you need to #pragma warning(disable:4996). Supposedly you could just define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS but it didn't work for me..

Comment: Those `_s` functions are now part of C1X Annex K.

Comment: And they are certainly an improvement on the MS interface, which is thus non-conforming. Though not that much of an improvement, and there usefulness is much under debate.

Answer (score 1):

You upgraded your IDE and also upgraded your Microsoft libraries.  Frankly you can continue to use your old libraries as they continue to be kept (for backwards compatibility) although Microsoft has said that they are going to actually start taking out some of these older functions.  I would say that if you're developing forward then you can use the newer functions; if you're developing backwards (or not worrying what the version is) then you might want to use the older functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting the Microsoft platform, by all means use them. Even if you're not, you can always implement them yourself when (or if) you need to port your software to a non-Microsoft platform.

Worst case is that you end up using a few `#ifdef`s to conditionally compile.

Answer (score 1):

They're being considered for standardization, as far as I'm able to tell.  The proposal is [TR 24731](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#24731).

As for whether it's a good idea to use them, I'd say yes.  I don't much like the way they catch errors but I believe you can provide them with your own handler.  If you need cross-platform compatibility you have two choices: implement them with macros on the non-Windows platforms or turn off the deprecation warnings.

After doing a review through a large codebase I determined that it's nearly impossible to get all programmers to use the C standard library functions for string manipulation correctly, so everything that aims to correct that is a welcome addition.

Comment: The problem is that MS made the step of unilaterally introducing the functions as if they were a standard and "deprecating" the "C" functions that were in the standard at the same time.  It seems to me yet another way to force you to stay with their tools.

Comment: That's overly skeptical.  They made a small internal improvement on the C standard library functions and rolled it into their public releases as well as submitting it for standardization.  If it was a deliberate ploy to increase their market share, why try to standardize it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the standard functions and disable whatever sadistic warnings Microsoft has turned on by default to discourage you from writing standards-conformant code. I seriously doubt the "_s functions" will ever be added to standard C (though they have been proposed) since they are an invention of a single vendor and have never been implemented by any other vendor. (Hey let's incorporate all of POSIX into the C standard while we're at it...)